# A question for Riesz lemma

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

https://mathprelims.wordpress.com/2008/07/17/rieszs-lemma/ Here is the proof of Riesz lemma. I just wonder why we require the linear subspace to be closed, what happens if the linear subspace is open? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Reminder, the opposite of closed subspace is *not* open subspace. The only open subspace of any Banach Space is the entire space itself.

Comment: But in general, if a set is not closed in a metric space, there is no guarantee that the distance between points in the complement of the set and the set is nonzero, for example consider the boundary of the open unit ball.

Answer (score 3):

I will adopt the notation used in the link in the question.
In the proof of the Riesz Lemma you need the fact that the subspace $Y$ is closed for proving that $a>0$. Indeed the fact that $Y$ is closed is used in the following way: once $a$ is defined to be $a:=\inf_{y\in Y} \| v-y\|$ for the fixed $v\in Z\setminus Y$, if by contradiction it happens that $a=0$ it means that there exists a sequence $y_n\in Y$ such that $\|v- y_n\|\to0$, that is $y_n$ converges to $v$, and since $Y$ is closed (by assumption) this implies that $v\in Y$, that is a contradiction.

This is fundamental in the proof, in fact in infinite-dimensional spaces it can happen that a proper non-closed subspace is dense; a basic example is the subspace of $C^\infty_c(I)$ functions in $L^2(I)$ on some interval $I$. So if a subspace $Y$ is dense in a normed vector space $Z$, then for any $v\in Z$ there is a sequence $y_n\in Y$ converging to $v$, therefore it happens that $\inf_{y\in Y} \|v-y\|=0$ for any $v\in Z$ and the proof of Riesz Lemma doesn't work.